# Test Account Setup for PayFlow Link and PayPal Payments Advanced

Tags: payflowlink, paypal

I am trying to setup a test account to test my module which will work for PayFlow Link and Paypal Payments Advanced. I am following this [tutorial](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929/).

The problem is that I don't have "PayPal Express Checkout" feildset in my settings. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gu6a.jpg) is an image of it. The field set also appears in this [paypal tutorial on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyiv3ndRcZI).

Also when ever I try to send a request to payflow api, it always says "User Authentication Failed" although all the parameters are correct.

I have setup a test account for Paypal Manager.

Answer (score 0):

The field in question is expecting the primary email address of the PayPal account you will be using to accept Express Checkout (PayPal) payments. You can specify both a live account and a sandbox account.

"User Authentication Failed" indicates your credentials are not correct. You should be using the same credential you use to log into the manager:

USER=username&VENDOR=merchantlogin&PARTNER=PayPal&PWD=yourpassword